# apache passenger deploy rails only show directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, passenger, public

I've looked all google results, and non of them helps:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/example.com/current/public
    <Directory /var/www/site/example.com/current/public>
        Options -Multiviews
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and as you can see, the app is deployed into:

```
/var/www/site/example.com/current/public
```

though Capistrano, where my app don't have an index page, but rails suppose to use the root I setup in the route file instead

But when I enter the url of, it only shows the public directory with its

As for the logs:

```
NO log in the rails log directory
No log for all the apache
```

Comment: could you try `passenger-status`?

Comment: Yes, I later found the issue is I shouldn't sudo passenger-install-apache2-module, I should rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module

Answer (score 0):

I later found the issue is I shouldn't sudo passenger-install-apache2-module, I should rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module

It is annoying since there is no hint from either passenger or apache telling that the passenger seems wasn't running, even the apache config has included passegner module and restart ok